# I'm having a problem with Python programming

Tags: python

First of all hi, I'm new to StackOverflow. Please let me know if I have any mistake.

I have a homework due by Tuesday and this homework has to be done in Python. However, there is a problem in my project and I will try to solve it here as I can't understand what the problem is about. I would be very happy if you could help.

Note: This project is "A program that takes customer type and loan amount from user and prints first 12 months loan amount list."

The overall code structure of the page where I got the error is like this:

```
consumertype = ['mortgage', 'individual', 'corporation']
interestrate = [15.3, 25.2, 20.4]

consumertype = input("Enter your consumer type: ")
loanamount = float(input("Enter your loan amount"))



if consumertype =='mortgage':
    print("interst rate of mortgage is", 15.3)
if consumertype =='individual':
   print("interest rate of individual is", 25.2)
if consumertype =='corporation':
    print("interest rate of corporation is", 20.4)


  

for i in range(12):
    totalinterest = loanamount * (interestrate/100)*(i+1)
    totalpayment = totalinterest + loanamount
    monthlypayment = totalpayment/12


TimeRange = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
for i in TimeRange:
    print ("You will pay", monthlypayment, "$ on", TimeRange, "th.month")
```

Problem: An error was found on line 20. However, in the sources I researched, I realized that it is not possible to "list" within a list. But I don't have the slightest idea how to fix this error because I don't understand python at all. I just want to give the assigned homework and graduate this year.

It shows an error that says in Terminal on line 20. This is exactly the code found on line 20:

```
    totalinterest = loanamount * (interestrate/100)*(i+1)
```

I am sharing for you a screenshot taken in visual code
[Please view this screenshot and browse the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMuiR.jpg)

Can you help me please ?

Comment: You cannot divide by a list. You need the value in the list and not the list itself.

Comment: Value of `interestrate` is `[15.3, 25.2, 20.4]`. What do you expect to get when dividing it by 100?

Comment: Hello, I got this function from friends at other university. They said that everything would work perfectly with this formula, but it didn't work as stated.
The user was asked to create a program that takes the customer type and loan amount and prints the first 12-month loan amount list.

Comment: @user56700 Yes, I'm aware, we got this formula from other friends at the university. He said this would fix everything and it would work, but it didn't work as promised. What can I do about this issue? Can you give some information?

Comment: Also ask the person who gave you the broken code? Presumably you're expected to write your own homework. (Asking here would be fine if you're stuck.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To increase the chances to get your questions answered, make sure to read and follow [Stack Overflow's guide on How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Give a specific title that contains your problem, and don't make your post too personal.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні This was your friend's homework last year, from whom I got the codes. That's why he said use this, it will solve your problem. That's why I used this formula, but it didn't work for me. Thanks a lot for your nice comment. Since I don't know how to use Stackoverflow much, I try to be cautious when answering or asking questions. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could change this pair of lists

```
consumertype = ['mortgage', 'individual', 'corporation']
interestrate = [15.3, 25.2, 20.4]
```

to a dict

```
interest_rates = {
    'mortgage': 15.3,
    'individual': 25.2,
    'corporation': 20.4
}
```

then to get the current interest rate instead of

```
if consumertype =='mortgage':
    print("interst rate of mortgage is", 15.3)
if consumertype =='individual':
   print("interest rate of individual is", 25.2)
if consumertype =='corporation':
    print("interest rate of corporation is", 20.4)
```

you could

```
try:
    interestrate = interest_rates[consumertype]
except KeyError:
    raise KeyError(f'Invalid consumer type entered: {consumertype}')
```

Then for your remaining code `interstrate` will be a single `float` to do your calculations instead of a list.

Answer (score 2):

Interestrate is a list, so the line with the error will not work.

You need a way to link the consumertype to a interest rate, this can be done with a dictionary:

```
interest_rates ={'mortgage': 15.3, 'individual': 25.2, 'corporation': 20.4}
```

you can then get the interest rate from the input of the consumer type:

```
interestrate = interest_rates.get(consumertype)
```

Corrected code:

```
interest_rates = {'mortgage': 15.3, 'individual': 25.2, 'corporation': 20.4}

consumertype = input("Enter your consumer type: ")
loanamount = float(input("Enter your loan amount"))

interestrate = interest_rates.get(consumertype)

if consumertype == 'mortgage':
    print("interst rate of mortgage is", 15.3)
if consumertype == 'individual':
    print("interest rate of individual is", 25.2)
if consumertype == 'corporation':
    print("interest rate of corporation is", 20.4)

for i in range(12):
    totalinterest = loanamount * (interestrate / 100) * (i + 1)
    totalpayment = totalinterest + loanamount
    monthlypayment = totalpayment / 12
    print("You will pay", monthlypayment, "$ on", (i+1), "th.month")
```

Answer (score 2):

Jack.
The issue you are facing is because the `interestrate` is a list and so cannot be divided by `100` which is of `int` type. I noticed a few ways you could improve the code. Here are my suggestions:

**1. Use a dictionary to map the `interestrate` list to the `consumertype`list.**

The change would look like this:

```
consumertype = ['mortgage', 'individual', 'corporation']
interestrate = [15.3, 25.2, 20.4]
```

to

```
interest_rates = {
    'mortgage': 15.3,
    'individual': 25.2,
    'corporation': 20.4
}
```

**2. Do not use these many `if` statements in code. [Unless necessary]**

After you get the `consumertype` and `loanamount` from the user, use dictionary methods to get the `interestrate` value for that specific `consumertype`.

My suggested change would look like this:

```
if consumertype =='mortgage':
    print("interst rate of mortgage is", 15.3)
if consumertype =='individual':
   print("interest rate of individual is", 25.2)
if consumertype =='corporation':
    print("interest rate of corporation is", 20.4)
```

to

```
if (interestrate:=interest_rates.get(consumertype, None)):
    print("Interest rate of mortgage is", interestrate)
else:
    print("Please verify if the right consume type is entered.")
```

**3. Avoid code repetitions whenever you can.**

As you can see in your code, there are two loops which are essentially running the same number of times. If you look closer, you can see that you can combine these two loops.

So the change would be

```
for i in range(12):
    totalinterest = loanamount * (interestrate/100)*(i+1)
    totalpayment = totalinterest + loanamount
    monthlypayment = totalpayment/12


TimeRange = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
for i in TimeRange:
    print ("You will pay", monthlypayment, "$ on", TimeRange, "th.month")
```

to

```
for i in range(12):
    totalinterest = loanamount * (interestrate/100)*(i+1)
    totalpayment = totalinterest + loanamount
    monthlypayment = totalpayment/12
    print ("You will pay", monthlypayment, "$ on", i+1, "th.month")
```

**Final code**

```
interest_rates = {
    'mortgage': 15.3,
    'individual': 25.2,
    'corporation': 20.4
}

consumertype = input("Enter your consumer type: ")
loanamount = float(input("Enter your loan amount: "))

if (interestrate:=interest_rates.get(consumertype, None)):
    print("Interest rate of mortgage is", interestrate)
else:
    print("Please verify if the right consume type is entered.")


for i in range(12):
    totalinterest = loanamount * (interestrate/100)*(i+1)
    totalpayment = totalinterest + loanamount
    monthlypayment = totalpayment/12
    print ("You will pay", monthlypayment, "$ on", i+1, "th.month")
```

**Note:** The code requires Python3.8 or greater.

**References:**

1. ":=" operator: https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/
2. Dictionary: https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

Comment: When I try this code structure, I get the error Time range is not defined. But thanks!

Comment: @Jack I have fixed the code. Can you try again and let me know?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem relating to the question is that `interestrate` is a list and not a numeric type, hence Arithmetic Operations Fail on it. The problem can be solved by using a dictionary as:

```
interestrate = {'mortgage':15.3, 'individual':25.2, 'corporation':20.4}
```

And replacing `interestrate` with `interestrate[consumrtype]`
Though not the current question, the code had several other issues that have been resolved in this code:

```
# Using Dicts Instead of a list to prevent extra time consumption in searching
interestrate = {'mortgage':15.3, 'individual':25.2, 'corporation':20.4}

consumertype = input("Enter your consumer type: ")
loanamount = float(input("Enter your loan amount"))



if consumertype =='mortgage':
    print("interst rate of mortgage is", 15.3)
if consumertype =='individual':
   print("interest rate of individual is", 25.2)
if consumertype =='corporation':
    print("interest rate of corporation is", 20.4)


  

for i in range(12):
    # Here interestrate[consumertype] refers to the interest rate of the consumer
    # type entered by the user
    totalinterest = loanamount * (interestrate[consumertype]/100)*(i+1)
    totalpayment = totalinterest + loanamount
    monthlypayment = totalpayment/12
    # There is no need of using a another function as it will unnecessarily increase 
    # the complexity, so Here we display the interest at the same time as 
    # calculating it
    print ("You will pay", monthlypayment, "$ on", i+1, "th.month")
```

Comment: Thank you for these nice comments. I will save the edited code structure. I hope the problem is solved. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Since one of your inputs is a "Consumer Type" I'm guessing that you are trying to display a consumer type and monthly payment amount for each month of a year given the interest rate linked to that ConsumerType.

I suggest you create a dictionary that links Consumer Types to interest rates like so:

```
Interest_Dict={"Mortgage": 15.3, "Individual": 25.2, "Corporation": 20.4}
```

Then in this section of the code where you calculate the monthly repayment value you must replace interestrate with Interest_Dict[consumertype]

```
for i in range(12):
    totalinterest = loanamount * (Interest_Dict[consumertype]/100)*(i+1)
    totalpayment = totalinterest + loanamount
    monthlypayment = totalpayment/12
```

Your for loop to get the monthly payment amount though isn't correct. You need to change your for loop but based on your formula you don't really need a loop at all.

The monthly payment amount can be found directly by using any of these formulae:
[https://www.thebalance.com/loan-payment-calculations-315564#:~:text=To%20calculate%20the%20monthly%20payment,per%20year%20times%2030%20years](https://www.thebalance.com/loan-payment-calculations-315564#:%7E:text=To%20calculate%20the%20monthly%20payment,per%20year%20times%2030%20years))

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will take a look at this code structure

Comment: `Interest_Dict(consumertype/100)` is invalid syntax